# What is the fastest algorithm for intersection of two sorted lists?

Tags: algorithm

Say that there are two sorted lists: A and B.

The number of entries in A and B can vary. (They can be very small/huge. They can be similar to each other/significantly different).

What is the known to be the fastest algorithm for this functionality?

Can any one give me an idea or reference?

Comment: You can perform it in O(nlog(n)) by applying binary search in list A for all the elements in list B. If the size of lists are very different then preferably search in the larger list.

Comment: it seems that you're having a bad approach. Why are you asking about the fastest known algorithm instead of developing your own which wouldn't take unnecessary steps?

Comment: @syko I gave you working code below

Comment: Could you clarify if by `list` you mean `linked list`? The answer to your question depends on part on whether or not your lists support binary search.

Comment: @JohnColeman you can consider it as an array, not a linked list. So sure, you can use binary serarch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that `A` has `m` elements and `B` has `n` elements, with `m ≥ n`. Information theoretically, the best we can do is

```
   (m + n)!
lg -------- = n lg (m/n) + O(n)
    m!  n!
```

comparisons, since in order to verify an empty intersection, we essentially have to perform a sorted merge. We can get within a constant factor of this bound by iterating through `B` and keeping a "cursor" in `A` indicating the position at which the most recent element of `B` should be inserted to maintain sorted order. We use [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) to advance the cursor, for a total cost that is on the order of

```
lg x_1 + lg x_2 + ... + lg x_n,
```

where `x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = m + n` is some integer partition of `m`. This sum is `O(n lg (m/n))` by the concavity of `lg`.

Comment: Thanks! Here's a Python version of the described algorithm: https://gist.github.com/fjsj/9c9f7f36cfd3205343e333d86778433c

Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the fastest option but here's one that runs in `O(n+m)` where `n` and `m` are the sizes of your lists:

- Loop over both lists until one of them is empty in the following way:
- Advance by one on one list.
- Advance on the other list until you find a value that is either equal or greater than the current value of the other list.
- If it is equal, the element belongs to the intersection and you can append it to another list
- If it is greater that the other element, advance on the other list until you find a value equal or greater than this value
- as said, repeat this until one of the lists is empty

Comment: This is natural and might even be optimal for *linked* lists (where linear scans would be unavoidable). On the other hand if random access is possible (as in Python lists, which are really arrays) then something which uses binary search to find the next common element might be better, noticeably so when the lists are large and the intersection is small. It seems hard to say what the best approach is without knowing a bit more about the lists.

Comment: @JohnColeman That is correct. My answer is based on the assumption that the OP was talking about linked lists that are not backed by arrays internally (like Java's ArrayList or Arrays/Lists in many other programming languages) so that accessing elements is not possible in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and tested Python implementation that uses bisect search to advance pointers of both lists.
It assumes both input lists are sorted and contain no duplicates.

```py
import bisect

def compute_intersection_list(l1, l2):
    # A is the smaller list
    A, B = (l1, l2) if len(l1) < len(l2) else (l2, l1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    intersection_list = []
    while i < len(A) and j < len(B):
        if A[i] == B[j]:
            intersection_list.append(A[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif A[i] < B[j]:
            i = bisect.bisect_left(A, B[j], lo=i+1)
        else:
            j = bisect.bisect_left(B, A[i], lo=j+1)
    return intersection_list


# test on many random cases
import random

MM = 100  # max value

for _ in range(10000):
    M1 = random.randint(0, MM)  # random max value
    N1 = random.randint(0, M1)  # random number of values
    M2 = random.randint(0, MM)  # random max value
    N2 = random.randint(0, M2)  # random number of values
    a = sorted(random.sample(range(M1), N1))  # sampling without replacement to have no duplicates
    b = sorted(random.sample(range(M2), N2))
    assert compute_intersection_list(a, b) == sorted(set(a).intersection(b))
```